# If value changes for no apparent reason

Tags: macros, conditionals

I am trying to create a horizontal enumeration environment with 3 items per row. As seen in the example the `\ifferstitem` conditional seems to turn to TRUE from FALSE for no apparent reason (at least for me). I suspect there is an esoteric procedure concerning the value of conditionals but I have found nothing in the usual TEX books.

**A.** What is wrong with my code?

**B.** As I am not proficient with macros, would there be a better way to implement this? ( For example, I feel that `\taband` command could be avoided )

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{tabi}\stepcounter{tabi}
\newcounter{tabirow}
\newif \iffirstitem
\firstitemtrue 
 \newcommand{\taband}{&}
 \newcommand{\addand}{\iffirstitem \firstitemfalse TruetoFalse
                 \else\taband \& Added
                 \fi}
%If 3 items in the row then change row and reset tabirow
\newcommand{\hitem}{\ifnum \thetabirow<3  
                                    \addand 
                                    \hbox to 3em{\hfil \roman{tabi}) \thetabirow}
                                    \stepcounter{tabi}
                                    \stepcounter{tabirow}
                \else 
                                    \\[2ex]
                                    \firstitemtrue
                                    \setcounter{tabirow}{0} 
                                    \addand 
                                    \hbox to 3em{\hfil \roman{tabi})         \thetabirow}
                                    \stepcounter{tabi}
                                    \stepcounter{tabirow}
                \fi
           }
\newenvironment{henumerate}[1]
    {    \setcounter{tabi}{1}
        \setcounter{tabirow}{0}
        \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
        \hline
    }
    {\\\hline
     \end{tabular}
}

\begin{henumerate}{5}
\hitem First 
\hitem Second 
\hitem Wrong
\hitem D
\hitem E
\hitem F
\hitem G
\hitem H
\end{henumerate}
\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the value of the conditional inside a table cell.
Table cells in TeX are groups, so local assignment inside them are only active up to the `&` (or `\\`)

You can change this by making the assignments `\global`. Just add `\global` before every `\firstitemtrue` and `\firstitemfalse`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{tabi}\stepcounter{tabi}
\newcounter{tabirow}
\newif \iffirstitem
\global\firstitemtrue 
 \newcommand{\taband}{&}
 \newcommand{\addand}{\iffirstitem \global\firstitemfalse TruetoFalse
                 \else\taband \& Added
                 \fi}
%If 3 items in the row then change row and reset tabirow
\newcommand{\hitem}{\ifnum \thetabirow<3  
                                    \addand 
                                    \hbox to 3em{\hfil \roman{tabi}) \thetabirow}
                                    \stepcounter{tabi}
                                    \stepcounter{tabirow}
                \else 
                                    \\[2ex]
                                    \global\firstitemtrue
                                    \setcounter{tabirow}{0} 
                                    \addand 
                                    \hbox to 3em{\hfil \roman{tabi})         \thetabirow}
                                    \stepcounter{tabi}
                                    \stepcounter{tabirow}
                \fi
           }
\newenvironment{henumerate}[1]
    {    \setcounter{tabi}{1}
        \setcounter{tabirow}{0}
        \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
        \hline
    }
    {\\\hline
     \end{tabular}
}

\begin{henumerate}{5}
\hitem First 
\hitem Second 
\hitem Wrong
\hitem D
\hitem E
\hitem F
\hitem G
\hitem H
\end{henumerate}
\\

\end{document}
```

The problem which caused your use `\taband` is typical for dealing with TeX conditionals: There are some restrictions on which code can stand in the then and else blocks. This can be avoided by using `bool`s from `etoolbox` instead:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{tabi}\stepcounter{tabi}
\newcounter{tabirow}
\newbool{firstitem}
\global\booltrue{firstitem}
\newcommand{\addand}{%
  \ifbool{firstitem}%
    {\global\boolfalse{firstitem}TruetoFalse}%
    {&\& Added}%
}
%If 3 items in the row then change row and reset tabirow
\newcommand{\hitem}{\ifnum \thetabirow<3  
                                    \addand 
                                    \hbox to 3em{\hfil \roman{tabi}) \thetabirow}
                                    \stepcounter{tabi}
                                    \stepcounter{tabirow}
                \else 
                                    \\[2ex]
                                    \global\booltrue{firstitem}
                                    \setcounter{tabirow}{0} 
                                    \addand 
                                    \hbox to 3em{\hfil \roman{tabi})         \thetabirow}
                                    \stepcounter{tabi}
                                    \stepcounter{tabirow}
                \fi
           }
\newenvironment{henumerate}[1]
    {    \setcounter{tabi}{1}
        \setcounter{tabirow}{0}
        \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l |}
        \hline
    }
    {\\\hline
     \end{tabular}
}

\begin{henumerate}{5}
\hitem First 
\hitem Second 
\hitem Wrong
\hitem D
\hitem E
\hitem F
\hitem G
\hitem H
\end{henumerate}
\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought  that \global has to do only with definitions.